# How rare is a Voigtlander Braunschweig. Heliar 12cm f/4.5?

Tags: film, large-format, voigtlander

I have a hard time finding anything on the internet about a certain large format voigtlander lens. I have picked it up a few months ago from a fleamarket for the outstanding price of 2 euros; nothing else, just the lens. The seller had no idea what it was, and honestly neither do I. I have left it in my photography drawer ever since. Today I was cleaning some of my other minolta and olympus lenses, and I picked it up to conduct some research to it. I have seen similar models of "Voigtlander braunschweig. Heliar". The models ranged from 10.5 cm to 24 cm. But mine is a 12cm and I have been on the web for almost 1 hour and haven't found a single trace of this lens. Did I just stumble in front of a super rare Voigtlander lens? Or was it never featured on the web?

Please let me know if anyone knows anything about it.

[image: Voigtlander Braunschweig Heliar 12cm f/4.5]

[image: Voigtlander Braunschweig Heliar 12cm f/4.5]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This focal length was "normal" for "postcard" format 122 film cameras and a Heliar this length should just cover 3x4 or quarter plate.

While 122 film was still available into the 1960s or early 1970s, cameras made for it had been obsolete since the early 1920s, while quarter plate and 3x4 dropped out of popularity about the time press photographers switched from sheet film to 120 (in cameras like Rolleiflex vs. Speed Graphic and similar) -- say, around 1950.

Further, those formats were never terrifically popular compared to 6x9 cm/2x3 (sheet or 120 rolls), 4x5, and 5x7; 3x4 was mainly used for newspapers because the negative could be contact printed with a half-tone screen for compositing into a newspaper column and postcard/122 was never a major consumer format because few consumer photographers could consistently make images worth the extra expense of having printed on postcard paper.

All of this means 12 cm lenses in general (not just the Heliar) were relatively less common than the "normal" focal lengths for 35 mm and 828, 127, 120, and 4x5.  Further, Voigtlander made lenses mainly for their own cameras, and by the late 1920s they were effectively out of the less common formats -- it was 9x12 (would use 13.5 cm, usually), 6x9 on 120 (10.5 or 11 cm) and by the late 1930s, 35 mm (mostly 50 mm on fixed lens and folding cameras).

All that to say, the 12 cm Heliar is significantly less common than, say, a 13.5 cm or 10.5 cm; while not a great rarity, it's likely that many of those still around in working shutters are in service with the diehard 3x4 press camera and Graflex users (or people like Borut Peterlin shooting wet plate collodion in a postcard format camera).

Comment: I know it's hard/impossible to say definitively, but I'm just curious... What do you think of the €2 price tag? Amazingly underpriced find, or fair market price?

Comment: Heliars are excellent lenses for pre-WWII designs.  Better than Tessars, almost always (there's unit variation, of course), though both are hard to distinguish from a triplet unless in a situation where triplets are weak.  If the shutter works, that lens would be right at home on a 3x4 Speed/Crown, or a quarter plate camera of almost any sort.

Comment: Oh, and two Euro is an incredible deal.  If you can find out what it fits, that lens board is worth twenty to thirty times that figure, and if the glass is clean and the shutter works with reasonable accuracy, the lens in shutter is worth more than the board.